# IsCharAlphaNumeric && !IsCharAlpha == IsCharNumeric?

Tags: c, winapi

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99456) Microsoft support page shows that there is no Win32 equivalent to C Run-Time's `isdigit()`.

But there is [IsCharAlphaNumeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647483%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [IsCharAlpha](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Intuitively, this leads me to:
`IsCharAlphaNumeric() && !IsCharAlpha()` is equivalent to (the non-existent) `IsCharNumeric()`

But I may be missing something...

Can I safely assume that the above is correct?

Comment: If you're looking for a Win32-based alternative to `isdigit()`, you could use [GetStringTypeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318118(v=vs.85).aspx) passing in a one-character array, asking for `CT_CTYPE1` info and then checking the output flags for `C1_DIGIT` (and/or `C1_XDIGIT`, if you want to include hex digits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the semantics of `IsCharAlphaNumeric()` and `IsCharAlpha()`, there's no way to determine whether

```
IsCharNumeric(c) == (IsCharAlphaNumeric(c) && !IsCharAlpha(c))
```

holds for all `c`. And it might be reasonable that it doesn't hold, for example hexadecimal digits can be both, numeric and alphabetic.

In other words, you can not safely assume the equivalence.

Comment: You are the first one who understood my question. Thanks +1.

Comment: Hexadecimal consists of both numeric and alpha characters, but each individual character is just one of the two. We're not talking about digits, but about characters. A character is either a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or anything else. If `IsCharAlphaNumeric` dictates it is either in a-z, A-Z or 0-9, and `IsCharAlpha` dictates the character is either in a-z or A-Z. Then the equation above DOES hold. The format (like hexadecimal) is unimportant. It is simply interpreted as a string (array of characters).

Comment: @Daevius but `IsCharNumeric('a')` could return true, because 'a' is a hexadecimal digit and hence a numeric character. You need to know the desired and given semantics of the functions to know whether the equivalence holds.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense to me.

Just use `isdigit()`, it's mandated by C standards old enough to be implemented by Microsoft.

The best way to re-implement it, if really needed, is:

```
int isdigit(int character)
{
  return character >= '0' && character <= '9';
}
```

This works since C mandates that the encodings for the decimal digits are sequential.

Comment: Neither the `isdigit()` function included with the C standard library, nor your proposed re-implementation, are acceptable solutions. They are not locale-aware, which means they fall flat on their face when confronted with a locale where "digits" are something other than 0-9. For example, Arabic uses the digits ١٢٣,٤٥٦.٧٨, and ٩. Of course, this only matters for Unicode strings (in which case you'd use `iswdigit()`), but since the question is about Win32, and all Win32 strings are UTF-16, you can't afford to ignore it anymore. Writing apps that are not locale-aware is no longer viable.

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
function IsCharNumeric(ch: Char): Boolean;
begin
   //We have IsCharAlphaNumeric, and IsCharAlpha
   //So IsCharNumeric = IsCharAlphaNumber - IsCharAlpha
   Result := IsCharAlphaNumeric(ch) and (not IsCharAlpha(ch));
end;
```

Here are the test results for selected characters.

**Note**: Any character omitted is *"not"* numeric:

Code Character IsCharNumeric

- 32 "`(space)`": No
- 33 "`!`": No
- 34 "`"`": No
- 35 "`#`": No
- 36 "`$`": No
- 40 "`(`": No
- 41 "`)`": No
- 43 "`+`": No
- 44 "`,`": No
- 45 "`-`": No
- 46 "`.`": No
- 48 "`0`": **Yes**
- 49 "`1`": **Yes**
- 50 "`2`": **Yes**
- 51 "`3`": **Yes**
- 52 "`4`": **Yes**
- 53 "`5`": **Yes**
- 54 "`6`": **Yes**
- 55 "`7`": **Yes**
- 56 "`8`": **Yes**
- 57 "`9`": **Yes**
- 65 "`A`": No
- 66 "`B`": No
- 67 "`C`": No
- 68 "`D`": No
- 69 "`E`": No
- 70 "`F`": No
- 178 "`²`": **Yes**
- 179 "`³`": **Yes**
- 185 "`¹`": **Yes**

So, if you wanted to trim a string down to only characters that could be parsed into a number, then you lose:

- `-1234.56`

But gain

- `¹²³4.56`

On the other hand, some characters fail the `IsCharAlphaNumeric` test, when you'd think they would pass:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./
```

The first ASCII character to survive the `IsCharAlphaNumeric` test is, in fact, zero (`0`).